# Groovyc: unable to resolve class geb.spock.GebReportingSpec

Tags: maven, groovy, intellij-idea, dependencies

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2 Ultimate and created a Maven project.
Here's my pom file: http://pastebin.com/KQ6ARxj3

So I have this Geb Spec class: http://pastebin.com/AerXgCDh

And in my classpath there are all maven dependencies and those are getting downloaded, everything's at his place. Including: Maven: org.gebish:geb-spock:0.10.0

But when I right-click on my module and select "Make Module [Module]" it starts compiling my source files but stops with this error:

```
C:\Users\...\MyModule\src\test\groovy\MySpockSpec.groovy
Error:(1, 1) Groovyc: unable to resolve class geb.spock.GebReportingSpec
```

Why can't the groovy compiler resolve this? Maven builds the project successfull and IntelliJ can resolve everything, so what's wrong with the groovy compiler?

Comment: if maven can build and intellij not... how is there an error with groovy?

Comment: that's exactly what I'm confused about...

Comment: You can see the the problem again here on that screenshot: http://fs1.directupload.net/images/141209/8wms8586.png

Comment: @cfrick In case I got you wrong: The Error message starts with "Groovyc". That's how I know somethings wrong with the groovy compiler...

Comment: Maybe try mvn clean and re-import the maven.